# Convert a string attribute to embedding in Neo4j Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-data-science

I have the following node in my Neo4j graph (actually I have many of them, this is a representative node):

```
{id: 1, name: "John", last_name: "Doe", age: 40, city: "New York", credit_score: 5.5}
```

How to transform all the attributes of type string to an embedding vector.
Please advise how can I do this inside Neo4j using Cypher?

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j offers the capability to generate node embeddings, but that functionality is used to represent a node's position in relation to other nodes in a graph. It doesn't make sense to generate an embedding for a single node in isolation.

Here is the [documentation for node embeddings](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/1.8/algorithms/node-embeddings/).

In your example, it might make sense to create separate nodes and relationships for things like city or age (for a single year or for an age range.) This could give you a more interesting graph topology to use with node embeddings.

If you are specifically interested in using numeric node properties to inform the embedding vectors, take a look at the [GraphSAGE algorithm](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/1.8/algorithms/graph-sage/).